# How to automate command prompt(putty) action via selenium

Tags: selenium

My application requires to enter commands on command prompt(Putty) and then I need to verify that from web browser.
I have used selenium for web functionalities but How can i achieve this with selenium?
which extensions /library files i would require?

Answer (score 0):

Use Auto It (https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/[AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)) to automate the interaction with putty and run the script in Java using Execute command(or find the command specific to your programming language).